# Why does type deduction fail once, but succeed another time in two very similar cases?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I was trying to write a **function** that gives the **max size of** a given **list of types**, this was my first attempt...

```
template<typename T>
size_t maxsizeof() {
    return sizeof(T);
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
size_t maxsizeof() {
    if (sizeof(T) > maxsizeof<Args...>()) {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
    return maxsizeof<Args...>();
}

int main() {
    size_t a = maxsizeof<short,float,double>(); //FAILS
}
```

But this code **fails to compile** on the last recursive call of `maxsizeof<double>()` and says that it is an **ambiguous function call**.

This seemed a little weird to me as I have wrote base cases like that in the past, and it always worked, so I went ahead and wrote it with **actual parameters** as I am more experienced with....

```
template<typename T>
size_t maxsizeof_with_parameters(T num) {
    return sizeof(T);
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
size_t maxsizeof_with_parameters(T num, Args... args) {
    if (sizeof(T) > maxsizeof_with_parameters<Args...>(args...)) {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
    return maxsizeof_with_parameters<Args...>(args...);
}

int main() {
    size_t b = maxsizeof_with_parameters<short,float,double>(1,2,3);
}
```

And weirdly enough, **this worked**, but the only thing I did differently was *include* the parameters, *I didn't even use them*.

Why does this happen? What is an alternative way to write the function without the throw-away parameters?

(Preferably I would also want this to be able to be done at compile time, though I got rid of some constexpr's so we could get to the meat of the problem)

Comment: This is aside from your issue, but in C++14, `std::max` was made constexpr: `return std::max({sizeof(T), sizeof(Args)...});`

Comment: Yes, thank you I will probably use that instead, still very intrigued to know why it fails like it does.

Answer (score 0):

The call becomes ambiguous when the function is called with a single parameter. `maxsizeof<T>()` can instaniate the first function or the second. A template parameter pack (`Args...`) is allowed to be empty, which is the reason why the compiler doesn't know which one it should choose.

Comment: yes, but why does it work when I include the throw away parameters?

Comment: @JakeSchmidt This only happens with parameters. The compiler uses a process that determines the best function template to go with through something called "partial ordering".

Comment: I spent some time looking through the "overload-resolution" tag and I think I understand it now, thanks.